# Publishing Silverlight app with webservice

Tags: silverlight, web-services

I have SL app running on clients machine. It uses a webservice, which I can access locally from the machine and remote from local network. I got public ip to access the app and webservice and its ok to access the app and webservice separately. But when app is supposed to call webservice method the webservice complete method is never fired. Since I can access webservice from public ip I assume the issue is connected with connection to webservice in sl. In service reference settings I got http://publicIPAddress/websiteName/webserviceName.asmx The question is how to configure connection to webservice so that I can run SL app from public ip using the webservice methods?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have clientaccesspolicy.xml file in root folder?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. Should I have clientaccesspolicy.xml? What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Let me know if it doesnt do the trick for you.

Comment: I made clientaccesspolicy.xml as provided in the tutorial from the link and placed in in the root project directory, where the webservice files are, but still getting same error.

Should I link it somewhere or move it  ?